# Newsletter subscription error in Magento 1.9x

Tags: magento-1.9

There is an error coming in my site when I am subscribing with email from Newsletter subscription form.

I have checked in admin panel also, the email is not present in Newsletter subscription list.

It is giving an error -[image: Newsletter subscribe error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check whether you have same email registered as customer or not.

I think Magento checks in customers table apart from newsletter subscribers table when a user tries to subscribe to newsletter from global newsletter subscription form.

When an email address already exists in customer table as a customer, Magento does not allow email address to subscribe for newsletter from global form. Instead, registered user can manage newsletter subscription from his account panel.

I hope, I was clear enough to answer your question.

Please let me know in case of any confusion or query.

Comment: More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110817/magento-newsletter-check-if-guest-is-already-subscribed

You should be able to override this functionality and subscribe the customer to the newsletter for example.